# How to install FreeRTOS on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, installation, raspberry-pi, freertos

my goal is to run FreeRTOS from [this site](https://github.com/jameswalmsley/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS.git) on a Raspberry Pi.
I have build it using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` on a Linux machine.

Now I have this files/folders:

```
RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS/
├── build
│   ├── Demo
│   │   ├── Drivers
│   │   │   ├── gpio.d
│   │   │   ├── gpio.o
│   │   │   ├── irq.d
│   │   │   └── irq.o
│   │   ├── main.d
│   │   ├── main.o
│   │   └── startup.o
│   └── FreeRTOS
│       └── Source
│           ├── croutine.d
│           ├── croutine.o
│           ├── list.d
│           ├── list.o
│           ├── portable
│           │   ├── GCC
│           │   │   └── RaspberryPi
│           │   │       ├── port.d
│           │   │       ├── portisr.d
│           │   │       ├── portisr.o
│           │   │       └── port.o
│           │   └── MemMang
│           │       ├── heap_4.d
│           │       └── heap_4.o
│           ├── queue.d
│           ├── queue.o
│           ├── tasks.d
│           └── tasks.o
├── dbuild.config.mk
├── Demo
│   ├── Drivers
│   │   ├── bcm2835_intc.h
│   │   ├── gpio.c
│   │   ├── gpio.h
│   │   ├── irq.c
│   │   └── irq.h
│   ├── FreeRTOSConfig.h
│   ├── main.c
│   └── startup.s
├── FreeRTOS
│   └── Source
│       ├── croutine.c
│       ├── include
│       │   ├── croutine.h
│       │   ├── FreeRTOSConfig.h
│       │   ├── FreeRTOS.h
│       │   ├── list.h
│       │   ├── mpu_wrappers.h
│       │   ├── portable.h
│       │   ├── projdefs.h
│       │   ├── queue.h
│       │   ├── semphr.h
│       │   ├── StackMacros.h
│       │   ├── task.h
│       │   └── timers.h
│       ├── list.c
│       ├── portable
│       │   ├── GCC
│       │   │   └── RaspberryPi
│       │   │       ├── port.c
│       │   │       ├── portisr.c
│       │   │       └── portmacro.h
│       │   └── MemMang
│       │       ├── heap_1.c
│       │       ├── heap_2.c
│       │       ├── heap_3.c
│       │       └── heap_4.c
│       ├── queue.c
│       ├── tasks.c
│       └── timers.c
├── kernel.elf
├── kernel.img
├── kernel.list
├── kernel.map
├── kernel.syms
├── Makefile
├── objects.mk
├── raspberrypi.ld
└── README.md
```

What are the next step to bring FreeRTOS to the Pi?

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: How did you generate that directory map?

Comment: I use the command `tree`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get started take help from existing operating system recommended for raspberry pi like: `raspbian`. Where all the necessary things (bootloader) for booting a kernel is there. So install raspbian first, then from SD card you'll find raspbian's own `kernel.img`, rename it take backup and then copy the freertos's `kernel.img` into SD card, then try booting. Hopefully this will work. Make sure the RaspberryPi version and freertos versions are okay.

Comment: One remark to the actual version: The demo sources providing the BCM2835. This means it will work on a Rasp 1, not on a Rasp 3.

Comment: @Alex44 On which version of rpi did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: I replaced /boot/kernel7.img with the freertos's kernel, and I connect to rpi 2 model B with uart, but booting doesn't show anything on the screen